# Forming node set using minimum number of components

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a graph with `n` nodes. I am given k partitions of the graph, each partition contains m1, m2 ...mk nodes.

I want to find a subset from the components such that the union of nodes in these subsets gives the node set of the graph. In doing so I want to ensure that I use minimum number of components required. I am using python lists for node set and components. Let me give an example:

```
node set - [49,57,3,95,98,100,44,40]
components - [57, 49, 100, 44], [57, 3, 95, 44], [3, 95, 44], [95, 44], [98, 44], [100, 44], [44], [40]
```

So, if I select components `[49, 100, 44], [57, 3, 95, 44] and [98, 44]`. Union of these sets gives me the node set. I can also select some other combination with 4 or more components, but that is not desired.
Please could someone help!!
Thanks

**EDIT** - The original problem that I am trying to solve has following constraints:

1. Each node is numbered based on its relevance*
2. The difference between relevance of successive nodes in a component should be greater a given value. (order of nodes is important, mentioned in the next point)
3. The order of the nodes in a component should be same as their order in the original node set.

Comment: Are you using "component" and "partition" interchangeably here?

Comment: If the "components" can be arbitrary subsets of the node set, this problem is NP-Hard. See [Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: Is there a lower bound on the "given value" in constraint #2?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : No, lower bound is not specified.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I think the link to the problem would be more useful https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/problem-solving

Comment: @nish Thanks for the link. That is a significantly different, and much more tractable, problem. The solver is allowed to make up the subset to be solved on a given day, rather than being told existing subsets. Does it have a closing date? I don't knowing contribute to on-line challenges while they are active.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I don't know about the end date, but its quite an old post I think. I am solving just for practice and to become a better programmer. Not solving to compete.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the assumption that your "partition" or "component" can be any arbitrary subset of the node set, so that your problem is the optimization form of [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), a known NP-hard problem. Any constraints on the subsets may make it more tractable, so please add them to the question.

There is no known polynomial-time exact algorithm for any NP-hard problem, and one cannot exist unless [P==NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

You essentially have two choices, brute force and approximation. Brute force, which may work for small sets of subsets, just tries every possible solution, starting with the smallest and continuing until you find a cover.

Your example has 8 subsets, so there are 8 candidate solutions of size 1, (8*7)/(2!)=28 candidates of size 2, and (8*7*6)/(3!)=56 candidates of size 3. Since there is a solution of size 3, the algorithm stops there. That is quite feasible to compute. You can save some time by storing the unions of N subsets, and using them to compute the unions of N+1 subsets.

As expected for an exact solution to an NP-hard problem, the time grows exponentially with the problem size, so it does not scale to much larger problems.

Alternatively, the referenced article contains a greedy approximation algorithm. If neither of those ideas works for you, consider doing searches for "set cover" with any terms limiting acceptable approaches.

Comment: I suppose that integer program solvers may use "brute force" in the worst case, but in practice, they're often unbelievably faster than naive brute force.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Maybe some of the same techniques could be applied to this problem. However, I'm really hoping that there are some unstated constraints that will make it more tractable.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Thanks for your answere. I have updated my question, adding constraints given in the original problem that I was trying to solve